# How can I protect my key from Decompilation tools (reverse engineering) in Unity C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, encryption

I am facing some issues regarding security purpose in Unity. I performed encryption and decryption by using System.Security.Cryptography; on single key and I also applied Obfustcation but nothing happens.
Please tell me how can I protect my key from decompilation tools is there any way to protect or save your code or key ???

I tried dotpeek or dnspy software for decompilation and my all scripts were shown so is there any software or package to protect my key or not?

Comment: Please don't tag UnityScript if your question is about C#. They are different languages.

Comment: Obfuscation is used to obfuscate the code, not some values embedded into it. Also note that though in general those tools can make life of "hacker" harder they are in no way a guarantee of protection, so you should consider everything which is available to client as vulnerable/decompilable/hackable.

Comment: Please explain what is the code you want to protect. Possibly you will want to look into some kind of authentication/authorization (tough again - this also can be worked around on the client side).

Comment: Ask yourself - are you trying to solve a problem that the entire games industry failed to for many years until they could mandate internet connections and keeping some of the IP on servers that remain under *their* control?

Comment: You can make it hard .. so hard that hopefully any hackers consider it not worth the effort to decompile / decifer your encryption ... you can't fully and completely secure your data. Games and other software at some point in time is usually cracked, patched and modded by someone on the wide world .. it's just a matter of time and effort ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you send the key to the end user, it can be found and there is nothing that you can do to ensure otherwise.

If the key that you're mentioning is a symmetric encryption key, you can instead use asymmetric encryption, then you can ship the public key to clients and have a server that owns the private key.

If having a server is not possible, you can just make it harder for someone to retrieve the key. This is not trivial to achieve, and anyone persistent enough will probably be able to defeat it. A simple idea that you can use to obfuscate your code would be to modify asset packages that you're using to have parts of the key. As you make calls to these libraries, you can also retrieve parts of the key and reconstruct it.

Eg, if you have the DOTween library, modify its dll, so that when you call ﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿﻿transform.DOScaleY(), it returns half the key. Then do the same with another library. Have a singleton used for something else, that also has a method that gets those key parts and reconstructs the key.